# Dynamically loading class in Java Android

Tags: java, android, class

Looking for the best way that I can define a class without knowing its name at the time of compilation. In PHP, this is done as follows:

```
$className = 'testclass';
$myClass = new $className();
```

In contrast, already in Java so do not be. I know it's ClassLoader, but I'm not sure if Android does so the same thing. I would ask for a specific code or even tips on how I can do it.

Regards.

Comment: **Why** would you do such a thing?

Comment: Define a class or load an existing class?

Comment: @MarioStoilov I thought of a simple plugin system, which would be just loaded when the application starts. However, the plugin can dynamically add, so I do not know their names.

Comment: If you are looking for loading an existing class, use Class.forName(classname)

Comment: @robermann your reply is very helpful for me, thanks.

Comment: happy to help you, if you like I could write it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Reflection` in Java: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html

Please note it is not possible to list classes in a certain package using reflection though.

Answer (score 1):

You can load an existing class via [Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29); your class could also have a static initializer `static { /* your init code */ }` so that it could be run while loading the class.

Note also that all JDBC drivers are commonly loaded in this way.